# Gnuplot - xtics different from grid

Tags: gnuplot, axis-labels

The gnuplot grid appears at the same position as the xtics/ytics.

How can I get rid of the tic labels at some (not all) of the tics?

In my case I want to  have gridlines at every 0.25 in x and y directions (i.e. at 0|0.25|0.5|...). I only want tic labels in x direction at every 0.5 interval, i.e. at 0|0.5|1|1.5....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several possibilities.

1) Individual tic labels can be replaced with an empty string:

```
set xtics 0.25
set xtics add ("" 0.25, "" 0.75, "" 1.25, "" 1.75)
```

2) Use the same line type for major and minor tic grid lines. Use minor tics for the additional grid lines:

```
set grid lt 2, lt 2     # same linetype for major and minor grid lines
set grid xtics mxtics   # draw grid for both major and minor tics on x
set xtics 0.5           # major tics every 0.5
set mxtics 2            # minor tics at double frequency of major tics
```

3) Use normal xtics for your plot but use the x2 axis for the grid

```
set grid x2tics noxtics     # grid lines for x2 but not x
set link x2                 # x2 axis uses same range as x axis
set xtics 0.5               # define tics along x axis
set x2tics 0.25 format ""   # different tics along x2, no labels
```

Comment: I went with 3) but changed the last command to `set x2tics 0.25 format "" scale 0` to also hide the tic marks themselves.